# What is the life cycle when using notifierProvider?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

When a talk room is streamed in talk_room.dart, the UserProvider is used to load the user.
However, even though I have not added autoDispose to UserProvider, every time a new stream comes in, UserProvider's build function is executed the last time and the user's information is lost.
I have waited for print in the onDispose callback, but it does not run, so I assume that it is not disposed.
Please tell me why the build function is repeatedly executed.

user.dart

```
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:sumee/domain/model/user.dart' as model;
import 'package:sumee/domain/model/user_id.dart';
import 'package:sumee/infrastructure/user_repository.dart';

class User extends FamilyNotifier<model.User, UserId> {
  Future<void> load() async {
    state = await ref.read(userRepositoryProvider).getUser(userId: state.id);
  }

  @override
  model.User build(UserId arg) {
    ref.onDispose(() {
      // not printed
      print('dispose');
    });

    return model.User(
      id: arg,
      phoneNumber: '',
      profileImages: [],
      planedDescription: '',
    );
  }
}

final userProvider = NotifierProvider.family<User, model.User, UserId>(
  User.new,
);
```

talk_room.dart

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:sumee/domain/model/talk_room.dart';
import 'package:sumee/feature/me/me.dart';
import 'package:sumee/feature/user/user.dart';
import 'package:sumee/infrastructure/talk_room_repository.dart';

class ListTalkRoom extends AutoDisposeNotifier<List<TalkRoom>> {
  ListTalkRoom();

  Future<void> subscribe() async {
    final user = ref.read(meProvider);
    final stream = await ref
        .read(talkRoomRepositoryProvider)
        .listByUserId(userId: user!.id);
    final subscription = stream.listen((talkRooms) {
      for (final talkRoom in talkRooms) {
        final me = ref.read(meProvider);
        final userId = talkRoom.participants
            .firstWhere((element) => !element.equal(me!.id));

        final isExistTalkRoom = state
                .firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.id.equal(talkRoom.id)) !=
            null;

        if (!isExistTalkRoom) {
          print('load');
          ref.read(userProvider(userId).notifier).load();
        }
      }

      state = talkRooms;
    });

    ref.onDispose(subscription.cancel);
  }

  @override
  List<TalkRoom> build() {
    subscribe();
    return [];
  }
}

final listTalkRoomProvider =
    NotifierProvider.autoDispose<ListTalkRoom, List<TalkRoom>>(
  ListTalkRoom.new,
);
```

talk_room_list_page.dart

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:sumee/domain/model/talk_room.dart';
import 'package:sumee/domain/model/user_id.dart';
import 'package:sumee/feature/me/me.dart';
import 'package:sumee/feature/user/user.dart';
import 'package:sumee/presentation/page/talk/feature/list_talk_room/list_talk_room.dart';
import 'package:sumee/presentation/router/router.dart';
import 'package:sumee/presentation/theme/color_theme.dart';

class TalkRoomListPage extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const TalkRoomListPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final state = ref.watch(listTalkRoomProvider);
    final currentUser = ref.watch(meProvider);

    final tabController =
        useTabController(initialLength: TalkRoomListTab.values.length);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('トーク'),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: tabController,
          tabs: TalkRoomListTab.values.map((e) => Tab(text: e.jp())).toList(),
          labelColor: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: tabController,
        children: TalkRoomListTab.values.map((tab) {
          return ListView(
            children: List.generate(state.length, (index) {
              final userId = state[index]
                  .participants
                  .firstWhere((element) => !element.equal(currentUser!.id));

              return TalkRoomCell(talkRoom: state[index], userId: userId);
            }),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TalkRoomCell extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const TalkRoomCell({required this.talkRoom, required this.userId, super.key});
  final TalkRoom talkRoom;
  final UserId userId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final user = ref.watch(userProvider(userId));

    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
          .pushNamed(RouteName.talkRoom.path),
      child: Container(
        height: 70,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 16,
          vertical: 8,
        ),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9999),
              child: Image.network(
                user.profileImages.firstOrNull ?? '',
                width: 56,
                height: 56,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                errorBuilder: (_, __, ___) => const SizedBox.shrink(),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 8),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    user.name ?? '',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displaySmall,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    talkRoom.lastMessage,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const Text(
              '3分前',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 8,
                color: ColorTheme.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

extension TalkRoomListTabExtension on TalkRoomListTab {
  String jp() {
    switch (this) {
      case TalkRoomListTab.all:
        return 'すべて';
      case TalkRoomListTab.friend:
        return '友達';
    }
  }
}

enum TalkRoomListTab {
  all,
  friend,
}
```

When a talk room is streamed in talk_room.dart, the UserProvider is used to load the user.
However, even though I have not added autoDispose to UserProvider, every time a new stream comes in, UserProvider's build function is executed the last time and the user's information is lost.
I have waited for print in the onDispose callback, but it does not run, so I assume that it is not disposed.
Please tell me why the build function is repeatedly executed.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 0):

You are updating state in your notifier with a new list on each stream event even if the calculation would have resulted in "equal" states, and because List does not use a deep equality, it will result in a notification from your notifier for every stream event.  You need to modify your state to not update if it would be the same state, or override updsteShouldNotify with a different policy than the default identity check.